# SQLException incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'

Tags: java, hibernate, native-sql

I can't figure this one out.

this query runs in sqlServer without error:

```
SELECT     COUNT(tjmm.MAINMISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID)
FROM         T_MOVEMENT_LEG ml INNER JOIN 
              TJ_MVLG_PARTMOV tjmp ON ml.MOVEMENTLEG_SID = tjmp.MOVEMENTLEG_SID INNER JOIN 
              T_MAIN_MISSION mm INNER JOIN 
              T_MISSION_PARTICIPANTS mp ON mm.DETCO_MISSIONPARTICIPANT_SID = mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID INNER JOIN 
              T_PARTICIPANT_MOVEMENT pm ON mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID = pm.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID INNER JOIN 
              TJ_MMIS_MISPART tjmm ON mm.MAINMISSION_SID = tjmm.MAINMISSION_SID AND 
              mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID = tjmm.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID ON 
              tjmp.PARTICIPANTMOVEMENT_SID = pm.PARTICIPANTMOVEMENT_SID 
WHERE         (mm.IN_USE = 1) AND (mp.IS_OPS = 1) AND (pm.IS_OPS = 1) AND 
              (ml.LEGEFFECTIVE_STARTDATE < { fn NOW() }) AND (ml.LEGEFFECTIVE_ENDDATE > { fn NOW() }) AND 
              (ml.IS_CANCELED = 0)
```

Transformed it to @Formula :

```
@Formula("select count(tjmm.MAINMISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID) "
        + "FROM T_MOVEMENT_LEG ml INNER JOIN "
        + "TJ_MVLG_PARTMOV tjmp ON ml.MOVEMENTLEG_SID = tjmp.MOVEMENTLEG_SID INNER JOIN "
        + "T_MAIN_MISSION mm INNER JOIN "
        + "T_MISSION_PARTICIPANTS mp ON mm.DETCO_MISSIONPARTICIPANT_SID = mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID INNER JOIN "
        + "T_PARTICIPANT_MOVEMENT pm ON mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID = pm.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID INNER JOIN "
        + "TJ_MMIS_MISPART tjmm ON mm.MAINMISSION_SID = tjmm.MAINMISSION_SID AND "
        + "mp.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID = tjmm.MISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID ON "
        + "tjmp.PARTICIPANTMOVEMENT_SID = pm.PARTICIPANTMOVEMENT_SID "
        + "WHERE (mm.IN_USE = 1) AND (mp.IS_OPS = 1) AND (pm.IS_OPS = 1) AND "
        + "tjmm.MainMission_SID = MainMission_SID AND"
        + "(ml.LEGEFFECTIVE_STARTDATE < NOW()) AND (ml.LEGEFFECTIVE_ENDDATE > NOW()) AND "
        + "(ml.IS_CANCELED = 0)")
private Integer opsCount;
```

changed the `NOW()` and added the link to the the pojo Id : `tjmm.MainMission_SID = MainMission_SID`

Anyone has idea where I have the fault in the formula?

Comment: i see you missed a space at the end of: + "tjmm.MainMission_SID = MainMission_SID AND"

Comment: @Pienterekaak aargg, can't test it until tomorrow but that's indeed a very good candidate, thanks already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short story: wrap the content of @Formula with braces

```
// instead of this
// @Formula("select count(tjmm.MAINMISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID) "
// use this
@Formula("( select count(tjmm.MAINMISSION_PARTICIPANT_SID) "
          ...
         ")")
```

Longer story: the @Formula mapping, represents "column like" expression. As documented here:

- [5.1.4.1.5. Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3147)

it can contain any statement resulting in select like this:

```
SELECT
  column1,           
  column1 + column2, // expecting columns contain number
  column1 * column2,
  ...
```

But this won't work

```
SELECT
  column1,           
  ...
  SELECT count(*) FROM OtherTable, // this won't work
```

Because such statement must be wrapped in braces

```
SELECT
  column1,           
  ...
  (SELECT count(*) FROM OtherTable), // working while wrapped with ()
```

And that is the issue with the `@Formula` above